# insert query only if mysql enum value is set to 'Yes'

Tags: php, mysql

i amn trying to run an insert query to insert the NOW() time and date only if certian enum values in my table are set to yes.

my table has 4 columns 'form1_completed', 'form2_completed', 'form3_completed', 'form4_completed'
the columns will be yes or no.

i am using this query to try and insert the current time and date into the database, its inserting but it doesnt pay attention to the where clause and just inserts anyway, can someone please show me what im doing wrong

```
$query2 = "IF (SELECT * FROM `supplier_session` WHERE `form1_completed` = 'Yes' AND `form2_completed` = 'Yes' AND `form3_completed` = 'Yes' AND `form4_completed` = 'Yes') INSERT INTO `supplier_session` (`completed_date`) VALUES (NOW());
WHERE `user_IP` = '$ipaddress '";
```

Comment: `form1_completed` = 'Yes'

Comment: Well, why are you inserting new value to the same table, is that not meant for the same row update?

Comment: and "WHERE `user_IP` = '$ipaddress '" belongs to which table and which query?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
WHERE `form1_completed` = Yes
```

use

```
WHERE `form1_completed` = 'Yes'
```

Comment: thanks i fixed that, although its still inserting even if the form columns = 'no'? why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ...) INSERT INTO ...
```

`EXISTS (subquery)` is true when the subquery returns any rows.

Or you could do:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...) INSERT INTO ...
```